How can I perform geoip-based routing on Ubuntu without kernel modules?
I have a container-based VPS (Ubuntu 22.04, kernel 4.4.0), and I want to add some geoip-based rules to its routing table.
Unfortunately, every tutorial I can find relies on xtables-addons, which requires a kernel module xt_geoip. I can't update kernel on my VPS, thus I can't install the module. So that's not an option.
Are there other ways of doing the same thing? Or will I have to manually add a bunch of address ranges using regular iptables rules?
